# Phpmyadmin with symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm looking how to access database with something like phpmyadmin using Ubuntu and Symfony 3.4 (I will have to work with this kind of symfony version soon).

```
php bin/console server:start


[OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

But when I try `localhost:8000/phpmyadmin` it's not working. I think there is a specific url when we are using this light servor, but I can't find the symfony documentation about it.
Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Can't create the database.

MySql is installed

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql

dbconfig-mysql                  install
libmysqlclient20:amd64          install
libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64          install
mysql-client-5.7                install
mysql-client-core-5.7           install
mysql-common                    install
mysql- server                   install
mysql-server-5.7                install
mysql-server-core-5.7           install
php-mysql                       install
php7.0-mysql                    install
```

I can connect to this page: `http://127.0.0.1:80/phpmyadmin/`

I can connect to the symfony app on this url: `http://localhost:8000/`

My parameters file

```
    # This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 80
    database_name: symfonyTest
    database_user: root
    database_password: MyPassword
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: b3b09e3360a0e09dfbb92723c767ec81d87235ff
```

But still `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work, It is an internal Symfony server, you should install PHPMyAdmin separately and set up a web server on your computer. also, you can use mysql workbench to have something like PHPMyAdmin in ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, but after is it possible to use the internal Symfony server with the phpMyAdmin ? Or it has to be with wamp/lamp ?

Comment: you can use both at the same time(with two different servers, one symfony internal server, and wamp/lamp), but with Symfony server, you can not run PHPMyAdmin but you can run symfony on wamp/lamp.

Comment: Ok thanks, I made the phpmyadmin installation so the url `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` works. But when I try `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` to create an empty daatbase from the symfony folder nothing happens and I have to stop with ^Ĉ

Comment: just google and read Symfony setup guideline, you should connect a database to your Symfony. change the config file in symfony. follow the Symfony website.

Comment: I followed this already, but may be I made some errors with ports ? The internal symfony servor is on port 8000 and the apache - phpmyadmin is on port 80 : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine.html

Comment: It is webserver port not database the mysal port is 3306. Make sure mysal is installed and symfony connected to right port

Comment: I have edited the first message, then I saw your comment; indeed replacing port 80 by 3306 made it work...but I didn't see anywhere in the documentation the port was this one.
If I understand right now. My symfony run in port 8000 / apache in port 80 / database in port 3306. I think I'm good, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

On symfony 4, I unzipped [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) into my symfony's project's `public/` folder

I can then access it using symfony's server via

```
localhost:8000/phpmyadmin/index.php
```

Comment: Doing so, you give pubic access to everybody to your phpmyadmin. I'm not sure this is a good practice.

Comment: @Minirock Sure, keep it for dev purpose